# Permute function calls

Tags: algorithm, scala, code-generation

I want to run a list of transformations on a dataset. Input and output of those transformations are type-wise always the same, so I can choose an order arbitrarily. In the end, I want to evaluate how the different orders perform (quality of the output data, computing performance and so on). So I give a file to the program where each line contains a function identifier and I run it like this:

```
// read lines of file into plan
for (x <- plan) {

  val temp : myDataType

  x match {
    case "Func_A" => temp = myData.map(y => funcA(y))
    case "Func_B" => temp = myData.map(y => funcB(y))
    ...
  }

  myData = temp
}
```

`myDataType` is an **immutable** collection which forces me to use these temporary variables. `plan` can contain possibly 20 lines/function identifiers which would lead to a lot of copy operations. So I am looking for a better solution. My dream would be to chain all the `map` functions like this, where `write` is just a function to collect statistics and write them to disc, no temporary variables needed:

```
plan match {
  case "Plan_A" => myData.map(x => funcB(x)).map(x => funcA(x)).map(...).write
  case "Plan_B" => myData.map(x => funcA(x)).map(...).map(x => funcA(x)).write
  ...
}
```

However, in this case, I would need to know all (at least those I want to try) permutations in advance, and there will be a lot (20+ functions). I also looked into compile time/runtime code generation but it looks a bit like overkill to me.

So maybe you have some ideas how to solve this a bit more elegant.

Comment: Since you're using `map` here, that tells me that your `funcA()` etc. treat each data item independently, which means that instead of calling `map` many times, you could instead call it just once, passing it a function that applies all 20 transformations.  I don't Scala, but in Haskell, you can build functions that apply other functions; I'm sure there's a way to do it in Scala too.

Comment: You're right, but putting all transformations into a single `map` does not answer my question, it just pushes the problem somewhere else.

Comment: Just write a function that reads a list of functions from the input, and returns a function (I presume Scala has first-class functions?) that applies each of them in sequence to a given input value.  You can then run `map` just once, passing it this "do everything" function you just built.

Comment: Yes Scala supports this, too. I will try it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two things to be addressed here.

1. Chaining functions together
2. Getting a sequence of functions

**Note**: For simplicity I am assuming operating on `Int`, and therefore functions of type `Int => Int`. You said you are mapping to the same type.

### 1. Chaining

Assuming you have a sequence of functions and some data, you can do the following:

```
...
val plan: Seq[Int => Int] = ... // see my second point
...
val myData = List(1, 2, 3, 4) // immutable List

// Can use compose instead of andThen
val compositeFunc = plan.foldLeft((i: Int) => i)(_ andThen _)
val newData = myData map compositeFunc
```

Note you can compose the functions with `andThen` or `compose` (https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/pattern-matching-and-functional-composition.html)

### 2. Getting a sequence of functions (plan)

You can do this any number of ways:

- Define them in a map somewhere in your code
- Define them in code and select them using reflection
- Compile them at runtime

**Static definition in a map**

```
class MyFunctions {
  def f1(i: Int): Int = i * 2
  def f2(i: Int): Int = i * i
  def f3(i: Int): Int = i * i * i

  // Hardcoded map from string to function name
  // Avoids any reflection
  val funMap = Map[String, (Int) => Int](
    "f1" -> f1,
    "f2" -> f2,
    "f3" -> f3
  )
}

val funcs = new MyFunctions

val myData = List(1, 2, 3, 4) // immutable List

// Assume you read these from your file
val planFromFile = List("f1", "f3", "f2") // String function names

// Get functions using the hardcoded map
val plan = planFromFile map (name => funcs.funMap(name))

// Can use compose instead of andThen
val compositeFunc = plan.foldLeft((i: Int) => i)(_ andThen _)

// Map the function composition to your data
val newData = myData map compositeFunc
```

**Using reflection**

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}

class MyFunctions {
  def f1(i: Int): Int = i * 2
  def f2(i: Int): Int = i * i
  def f3(i: Int): Int = i * i * i
}

val funcs = new MyFunctions

val myData = List(1, 2, 3, 4) // immutable List

// Assume you read these from your file
val planFromFile = List("f1", "f3", "f2") // String function names

// Acts as a function wrapper that wraps a MethodMirror
// Note that all functions in Scala are objects ((Int => Int) is shorthand for Function1 ...)
class WrappedFunction(mirror: reflect.runtime.universe.MethodMirror) extends (Int => Int) {
  override def apply(v1: Int): Int = mirror(v1).asInstanceOf[Int]
}

// Returns function wrappers for each string
// Note for simplicity there is no code dealing with missing function , errors etc.
def getFunctions(names: Seq[String]): Seq[Int => Int] =
  names.map(s => new WrappedFunction(ru.runtimeMirror(funcs.getClass.getClassLoader)
    .reflect(funcs)
    .reflectMethod(ru.typeOf[MyFunctions]
      .decl(ru.TermName(s)).asMethod)))


val reflectedFunctions = getFunctions(planFromFile)

// Compose them from the generated functions
val compositeFunc2 = reflectedFunctions.foldLeft((i: Int) => i)(_ andThen _)

// Generate data
val newData2 = myData map compositeFunc2
```

I have not talked about compiling at runtime and I am assuming this is not your use case.

You can also combine the approaches and generate the map using reflection.

**EDIT** Obviously you can also use pattern matching instead of that map.. something like this:

```
def fromName(name: String): Int => Int = name match {
    case "f1" => f1
    case "f2" => f2
    case "f3" => f3
    case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("booooom!")
}
```

For more information on reflection see the docs: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html

Comment: That's simply great.